# refreshing 500k rows per day, what primary key to use?

Tags: sql-server, best-practices, clustered-primary-key

Usually I create a PK of type int/bigint for every table. But in this case I have some doubts.

I have a table which is updated many times a day, the total number of rows is around 500k, but they get refreshed few times a day.
Using update would be expensive, so for every batch of data to update I just delete the old rows (by a NC key) and bulkupload the new data.

Now my doubt is... I can just choose to have a bigint PK and forget about it, it will increase by 500k a day, and it will takes forever before to run out of values, but is there a better approach?

Comment: Why do you even have this int/bigint PK identity column, if you are deleting and re-inserting the new versions of the rows? You obviously have no Foreign Keys that reference this table. Why bother with an identity column that is useless?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ actually I would prefer to skip it, but I thought that was one of the sql ten commandments, every table should have a PK, I could use the NC key as PK... but it's made of 10 columns, and so far has proven to be unique only in theory...

Comment: I'd suggest you understand the difference between natural and surrogate keys and choose what best suits your requirements. Yes, properly formed tables should have primary keys. Your DBMS allows tables with one. Decide if this is appropriate for this particular circumstance and go with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd stick with `BIGINT`.

An `INT` takes up 4 bytes of space. On 500,000 rows, that works out to 2 million bytes, or just under 2MB per day of overhead (which is practically nothing these days).

Double that for `BIGINT`, which is 8 bytes in size, so 500,000 rows will need under 4MB of space.

We generally recommend `BIGINT` if you're going to add (or change) over 2 billion rows over the lifetime of the table or index.

While `INT` supports a range of 4 billion values from roughly -2 billion to 2 billion, people generally start their `IDENTITY` value at 0 or 1, cutting out half of the available range.

In a case where you're doing 500,000 a day, a `BIGINT` might be better for you. It's a good trade-off between storage and data churn in the medium to long term.